# Asking for forgiveness in islam

Tags: parents

I'm an orphan. When i was young there are times that i disobey my parents when they are still alive. My question is, is that true that Allah wont accept me and all my ibadah and wont look at me on judgement they. I repent and i regret it. But i'm feeling hopeless. Cause didnt have a change to ask my parents to forgive me, when they are alive.

Answer (score 1):

Salaam. Paraphrasing in English, God says

> `39:53` Say: "O My servants who transgressed against themselves, do not despair of the mercy of God. For God forgives all sins. He is the Forgiver, the Merciful."

and,

> `4:40` Indeed, God does not wrong the weight of an atom; and if it is good He will double it. And He grants from Himself a great recompense.

plus,

> `3:133` And race towards forgiveness from your Lord and a Paradise whose width encompasses the width of the heavens and of the earth; it has been prepared for the righteous.

I'm sorry you did not have a chance to apologize to your parents before they passed, however, the **good news** of the Quran is just that:

> `39:20` But those who reverence their Lord, they will have dwellings constructed upon dwellings, with rivers flowing beneath them. The promise of God, and **God does not break the promise**.

God has promised forgiveness, and *much more*.

Alykum As'salaam. Peace, from the source of peace.